Is this a correct bidirectional shift register

Is this a correct circuit for bidirectional shift register.

Can you edit the question to rotate the picture by 90 degrees to make it easier to read.

I have edited it.tell me weather it is right or wrong.

Why not just draw it in a simulator and test it yourself before building. BTW this may not sound like good advice but I can tell you that it is if you are the least bit interested in electronics.

Note that in practice, you could replace the AND gates with NAND, and then the OR with another NAND. This gives the same logic function (de Morgan equivalent) and typically implements smaller.

The circuit is a correct implementation of a bidirectional serial-in parallel-out shift register.
